# How to handle new nodes with draggable views?

Tags: views

I have been using draggableviews to allow for arbitrary sorting nodes on one of my views. My idea was to have the view show 20 items, and the draggableview show 30 items, ideally then the first 20 items are what shows up and the next 10 are the latest nodes so editors have nodes to pick from to add to the main view. Unfortunately once you save the form all 30 get a weight which means new nodes will show up on page 2 and won't be easy to add to the top 20. Did I set something wrong? Or is this how it's supposed to work?

Their docs mentioned a setting for "Behavior of new nodes" but I can't find this anywhere. I used grep on the module code and could not find this wording anywhere either so I'm guessing the docs are outdated?

I do have "New items appear bottom of the list" checked under Draggableviews: Weight if that makes any difference.

My only solution so far is to run this query every time a node gets inserted:

```
DELETE FROM `draggableviews_structure` WHERE `weight` > 19 AND `view_name` = 'my_draggable_view';
```

But this seems like a hack. There's gotta be a way to do this with the module, is there?